# Again! Spring MVC character encoding for POST method

Tags: spring-mvc, character-encoding, http-post

I've already spent hours trying all possible solutions through out internet. Here is the problem: I need to have some Farsi inputs from user and save them in database. But as a result all I see is a bunch of **question marks**. Things I've tried so far:

- My database is utf8 encoded and so is my database connection
- I use encoding filters in my *web.xml* and also map it to all addresses. and place the filter on top.
- All my jsp pages have the appropriate *<@page...>* tag on top of them.
- Etc...
  But no luck. The point is if I omit the encoding filter I don't get question marks but some distorted characters instead. So I'm pretty sure that the filter is doing something.

Do you have any guesses?

**[edit]** I'm sure it's not DB problem as well. since I can manually insert utf8 characters in my DB and read them by my application alright. I only have problem writing in DB.

**[more details]**
suppose I want to add a name to a list. So I enter the string and post it. I then will be redirected to the list of the names with the new name appended and the name is all in question marks. If I enter a Farsi text right from the controller i.e in my java code I still have the problem. That's why I think it's not the filtering's fault. Since I can read utf8 characters from DB I'm pretty much confused where exactly is the source of problem. Controller part or DAO part?

Comment: Are you sure the request contains UTF-8 encoded data? Do you use GET or POST?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. and I use POST

Comment: Some details and code could be helpful. When do you get the undesired results? Already in the controller or when the jsp is being rendered, or even later, viewing the page in a browser?

Comment: The Farsi characters can be sent in the request, but your Servlet/controller has to read them correctly. Which encoding/decoding filters are you using?

Comment: I use Spring.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter and set it's property to UTF-8. I feel like it's hibernate's problem in writing data but not reading. how likely is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! for those who deal with the same problem:
Make sure your database connection has it's **"useUnicode"** property set to true. Previously I had only enabled **"useEnconding"** and it was the main cause of the problem.

So this is how I fixed it:

```
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/CMS?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

The interesting part is that it will only cause problem writing in DB but not reading. That's why I hardly suspected my *jdbc* settings and wasted a whole day over this problem!